# How do I copy a file into my WAR's META-INF directory?

Tags: gradle, copy, war, meta-inf

I’m using Gradle 2.7.  I would like to copy an environment-specific file (context.xml) into my WAR’s META-INF directory (which is at the same level as WEB-INF).  I have this task set up in my build.gradle file

```
// Copy context.xml into the appropropriate directory.
war {
   def env = project.hasProperty('env') ? project.env : 'dev'
   from("${project.rootDir}/src/main/environment/$env") {
      include('context.xml')
      into('META-INF')
   }
}
```

However, when I run “gradle build”, nothing gets copied.  I have verified the file exists.  What else do I need to do to get this file to copy properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your script is configured correctly. It's stupid question (it should've failed at the very beginning) but have you applied `war` plugin?

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/33896879) you have a demo to compare the configurations.

Run:

```
jar -tvf <lib>.war
```

to verify if war contains appropriate file.